# Выборка из связанных таблиц Mysql

Tags: mysql

У меня есть 2 таблицы - `posts` и `users`. Я связал поле `id` в `users` с полем `autor_id` в `posts`. Как мне теперь в выборке поста из `posts` получить имя автора из `users`? Для этой цели *join* или *union* использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы используете framework, то запрос на получение данных будет примерно такого вида:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.`name` as `user_name`
FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON (posts.`autor_id`=users.`id`)
WHERE posts.`id`=?
```

Если вам потребуются еще какие либо данные из таблицы `users` вам нужно их добавить в секцию `select` и прописать алиас, на случай совпадения названия полей в обоих таблицах.

Comment: Фреймворком не пользуюсь, но Ваш запрос работает. Спасибо!

Comment: А для чего кавычки обратные нужны?

Comment: @Vlad - обратные кавычки mysql понимает, как имена столбцов, таблиц, баз данных. При их использовании исключается возможность возникновении ошибки например из-за названия столбца, которое совпадает с ключевым словом, например `group`

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить задачу двумя способами, либо задействовав оператор JOIN

```
SELECT
  p.id AS id,
  p.content AS content,
  u.name AS name
FROM
  posts AS p
LEFT JOIN
  users AS u
ON
  p.author_id = u.id
```

Или можно воспользоваться вложенным запросом

```
SELECT
  id,
  content,
  (SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = posts.author_id)
FROM
  posts
WHERE
  id = 145
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А для чего вообще связи в таблицах нужны, если всё можно в запросе решить?

Comment: @Vlad, имеются в виду внешние ключи вроде author_id или что-то другое?

Comment: Ну да. Я связал в phpmyadmin'е id одной с author_id другой таблицы. Для чего это нужно делать на уровне базы - если запросом можно получить выборку из несвязанных таблиц? Простите, за тупой вопрос - я этого момента не понял))

Comment: @Vlad, это как раз очень важно, вы не сможете без такой связи по-нормальному привязать данные. Обратите внимание в каждом запросе author_id используется (просто в разных местах). Без него, вы не сможете определить какому пользователю какой пост принадлежит. Можно сделать кросс-объединение, но в нем каждому пользователю будет сопоставлен каждый пост, но так как информации о связи нет, вы ничего толком с такой таблицей не сделаете. Внешний ключ позволяет такую связь установить.

Comment: @Vlad это нормальная практика для сохранения ссылочной целостности БД

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял.

Comment: @Reinq спасибо!